# Serial port splitter (1 output device -> 2 computers)

Tags: serial-port

Does anyone know how I can split a serial cable so the output from one device is connected as inputs to two different computers?

I try to connect the (-)(+)TX at the same to the two computer...
I get data but wrong data with "? , % " some wrong chars

Please can someone help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make sure to connect them with a [null-modem/crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem)?

Comment: "*... connect the (-)(+)TX ...*" - Differential signal?! What kind of "serial" is this, RS-422?  Typical serial connections are intended to be point-to-point unless explicitly designed as multipoint.  The line driver (the IC, not the SW) may not be able to cope with a split; long cables and/or small gauge conductor make it worse.  Are you positive that this is a one-way connection, i.e. there is no handshaking involved?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

from http://www.compuphase.com/electronics/rs232split.htm

You can of course buy RS232 splitters rather than make your own.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a hunt around electronics shops because this *used* to be a common requirement.

I think I've got a splitter in my "box" of old bits of kit.

It is much better to have a proper box because of the possibility of bleed over of the signals.